# sqlite calculating percentage

Tags: sqlite

I would like to select items from a table where their frequency count is less than 5% of the total amount.

For example, if I had a table of names, I would like to select the names that appeared less than 5% of the total.

Answer (score 6):

A simple `GROUP BY` would suffice I think:

```
SELECT name, 
       1.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names) AS percentage
FROM names
GROUP BY name
HAVING 1.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names) < 0.05 ;
```

Comment: is there a way to display the percentage?

Comment: Sure, edited the query.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases multiplying by 1.0 may not work casting is more reliable

```
SELECT name, 
       (cast COUNT(*) as real)/ (SELECT cast (COUNT(*)as real) FROM names) AS percentage
FROM names
GROUP BY name
HAVING (cast COUNT(*) as real)/ (SELECT cast (COUNT(*)as real) FROM names);
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide an example of when multiplying by 1.0 wouldn't work?

Comment: He probably means if the column isn't a numeric type